# Paypal : Angular Js paypal button is not redirecting to the payment page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am trying to test my paypal integration with using sandbox account credentials

this is my button code

```
    <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="3M2C8VGPZSHSW">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

the button is not redirecting anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer from this , it contains many example and helpful code
https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/validation